# Arranging text lines in R

Tags: r, text

My data is in this format. It's a text file and the class is "character". I have posted few lines from the file. There are about 14000 lines.

```
"KEY: Aback"  
"SYN: Backwards, rearwards, aft, abaft, astern, behind, back."  
"ANT: Onwards, forwards, ahead, before, afront, beyond, afore."  
"KEY: Abandon"  
"SYN: Leave, forsake, desert, renounce, cease, relinquish,"  
"discontinue, castoff, resign, retire, quit, forego, forswear,"  
"depart_from, vacate, surrender, abjure, repudiate."  
"ANT: Pursue, prosecute, undertake, seek, court, cherish, favor,"  
"protect, claim, maintain, defend, advocate, retain, support, uphold,"  
"occupy, haunt, hold, assert, vindicate, keep."
```

Line 6 and 7 is the continuation of line 5. Line 9 and 10 is the continuation of line 8. My struggle is how can I bring up line 6 and 7 to line 5 and similarly line 9 and 10 to line 8.
Any hints gratefully received.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't post my question completely earlier due to some error.  So was trying with few lines whether it works or not. It worked and so I re-edited full question. Thanks!

Comment: Oh okay. Yes every new line is supposed to start with KEY: , SYN: and ANT:

Comment: How did you get the data in this format to begin with...

Comment: @VincentBonhomme Isn't [:upper:] supposed to capitalize all the characters in the text.

Comment: @MichaelChirico I downloaded an online txt file using 'readLines' in r. The lines came like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing that comes to mind (your text is stored as `x`):

```
#prefix each line starter (identifies as pattern: `CAPS:`) with a newline (\n)
strsplit(gsub("([A-Z]+:)", "\n\\1", paste(x, collapse = " ")), 
         split = "\n")[[1L]][-1L]
# [1] "KEY: Aback "                                                                                                                                                                       
# [2] "SYN: Backwards, rearwards, aft, abaft, astern, behind, back. "                                                                                                                     
# [3] "ANT: Onwards, forwards, ahead, before, afront, beyond, afore. "                                                                                                                    
# [4] "KEY: Abandon "                                                                                                                                                                     
# [5] "SYN: Leave, forsake, desert, renounce, cease, relinquish, discontinue, castoff, resign, retire, quit, forego, forswear, depart_from, vacate, surrender, abjure, repudiate. "       
# [6] "ANT: Pursue, prosecute, undertake, seek, court, cherish, favor, protect, claim, maintain, defend, advocate, retain, support, uphold, occupy, haunt, hold, assert, vindicate, keep."
```